# How to get Readonly notification token for 'stream_rails' gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, getstream-io

I am using the stream_rails gem for my Rails App and want to develop a real time notification system in my app. For this purpose, I want to be able to generate a readonly token. Currently when I was going through the documentation here:
http://getstream.io/docs/#readonly-tokens

it did not provide any steps to generate readonly token for ruby app. Can someone please help me with this information on how to get one? Also please let me know if this readonly token has any expiration time (or) is it valid for the lifetime?

Comment: The Ruby client does not yet support generation of read only tokens, see [docs](http://getstream.io/docs/#readonly-tokens).

Answer (score 0):

Read only tokens don't have an expiration date. The python implementation can be found here:

https://github.com/GetStream/stream-python/blob/master/stream/feed.py#L31

This is currently not supported in the Ruby client. If you add this functionality, a pull request would be much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Will try to provide the changes for the Ruby client.